# how to get an movable pin on a map view iphone or ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, dictionary, view

how to get an movable pin on map view , so that user can move that pin and point out the specific location on the map. please tell me how to do this

thanks 
Kumar.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just hold your finger on the map for a few seconds and a pin appears.